# Google forms from scripts, trying to get addCheckboxGridItem option with one response per row

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build from scripts a google form using the codes

```
  var form = FormApp.create("New form");
  var formQ1 = form.addCheckboxGridItem();
  formQ1.setTitle(Title1);
  formQ1.setRows(Rows1);
  formQ1.setColumns(Colums1);
```

However, I would like to have the option to only accept one response per row

If I want one response per column I can have:

```
  var formQ1validation = FormApp.createCheckboxGridValidation().requireLimitOneResponsePerColum()
  .build();
  formQ1.setValidation(formQ1validation);
```

and it works fine, but what I need is one response per raw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem a way to handle the rows how you want in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-validation-builder#requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()) for CheckboxGridValidationBuilder. a workaround you can try would be to build your grid "sideways", which you can do by trying:

```
  var form = FormApp.create("New form");
  var formQ1 = form.addCheckboxGridItem();
  formQ1.setTitle(Title1);
  formQ1.setRows(Colums1);
  formQ1.setColumns(Rows1);
```

This way you can set the rule for one answer per column and it will behave as intended. You can open up a bug with Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com) to let them know this functionality is missing.